# How do I edit an MySQL 8 collation?

Tags: mysql, json, collation

I'm using MySQL 8.0.13 and I'm extracting data from JSON like this:

```
SELECT person.* FROM object, JSON_TABLE(attributes, '$.person[*]'           
COLUMNS (firstname TEXT PATH '$."firstname"')) person ORDER BY 
firstname COLLATE utf8mb4_sv_0900_as_cs ASC;
```

This works great but the case sensitive sorting does not work when it comes to the swedish characters åäö/ÅÄÖ. Like this:

- Eva
- Gunhild
- ÅAnna
- åGunhild
- åGunhild
- åOlle
- äAnna
- äEva
- äNils
- ÄOlle
- ÖAnna
- öEva
- ÖOlle
- öTore

As you can see Ö appears before ö and then Ö appears again etc.

Where can I find the collation and how do I edit it?

Comment: `Ö appears before ö` shouldn't uppercase letters come before lowercase ones? If I recall correctly, collation in MySQSL respects neither casing (will mix upper and lower) nor the order of accented letters unless binary is used. Specify `CHARSET=utf8` for the table and `collate utf8_bin` for the query or `CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin` for the table if you want binary ordering by default.

Comment: See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html

Comment: @marekful - Note that the OP is using `..._as_cs`, which implies "Accent Sensitive and Case Sensitive".

Comment: Smells like a bug.  Please file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com (and specify the specific version you are using).  That collation is hot off the presses.  Be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a test case with at least a few of the mispositioned words.

Comment: Ok I will report it. Thanks.